# Section between ball and a cone

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, volume

Ball $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le R^2$ and cone $z \ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ constitute a section. This section is a K $\subset \mathbf R^3$

How do I express this K in polar coordinates and how do I calculate the sections volume?

I know that:

$x = rsin\theta cos\phi$

$y = rsin\theta sin\phi$

$z = rcos\theta$

Comment: The "ball" $\;x^2+y^2+z^2\le0\;$ is just the point $\;(0,0,0)\;$ ...! Besides, a "section" is something that may be not well defined or, at least, is not standard. Did you mean "the three dimensional body bounded by..." ? Finally, the coordinates you mention are the spherical ones, not the (cylindrical, in fact) polar 3D ones.

Comment: Sorry I did little edit

Answer (score 0):

Impossible:  $^2+^2+^2 \leq 0$ (except for the single point $(0,0,0)$).

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, your "section" (not sure what that *exactly* is in this context) $\;K\;$ is the 3-dimensional body bounded by the (closed and full) sphere $\;x^2+y^2+z^2\le R^2\;$ and the cone $\;z\ge\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\;$, or: the body between the cone from below and the sphere from above.

Using cylindrical coordinates, we get that in order to evaluate the volume of $\;K\;$ (assuming it is what I wrote above) we need:

$$x^2+y^2=R^2-x^2-y^2\implies x^2+y^2=\frac{R^2}2\implies$$

$$\int_0^{R/\sqrt2} dr\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_r^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} r\,dz=2\pi\int_0^{R/\sqrt2}r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\,dr=$$

$$=\left.-\pi\frac23(R^2-r^2)^{3/2}\right|_0^{R/\sqrt2}=-\frac{2\pi}3\left(\left(\frac{R^2}2\right)^{3/2}-(R^2)^{3/2}\right)=-\frac{2\pi}3\left(\frac{R^3}{2\sqrt2}-R^3\right)=\frac{\pi R^3}3\frac{2\sqrt2-1}{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Yeah I mean that the ball and cone make up a "thing" and I want to calculate volume of the section between this cone and ball because these two things intersect each other and that is the volume that I am interested. Sorry for bad spelling English is not my main language